# Timelapse on after effects

Tags: after-effects

I have got 90 pictures of a building site (one per work day), and I would like to get about 10 seconds of video.
So, I would like to know how to generate image between my images on after effects (CS6) to get a smoother time lapse video ?

Thx in advance !

Answer (score 4):

The most-recommended way to do this is with [Twixtor](http://www.revisionfx.com/products/twixtor/downloads/), a pricey plugin for AE and other platforms. They offer a watermarked free trial. There are some free alternatives out there but I haven't used them so I can't say for sure they'll suit your need. One is [SloMoVideo](http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/) and if you google that you'll see videos from people who've tried it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the math(s):

90 images to make a 10 second video at a frame rate of 25 frames per second (fps) (in the UK) =

25 fps * 10 seconds = 250 frames

250 frames / 90 images = 2.778 frames per image

So each frame would need to be onscreen for just under three frames, which wouldn't look particularly smooth - for smooth motion you'd ideally have 25 images per second:

90 images / 25 frames per second = would only give you a total duration of 3.6 seconds of video, but it would be smooth.

This would look a lot smoother, but give you a shorter video.

Twixtor would attempt to interpolate between the frames, but works best on higher framerates than this - I suspect the results would look a bit unnatural (objects morphing out of nowhere).

The frame blending suggestion would probably look more natural, as it is just crossfading between each frame.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There's something off in your math. If you have to cover 250 frames of time with 90 frames of video, each frame is displayed about 3 times. If each of 90 frames were displayed for three seconds each, you'd get 270 *seconds* of video.

Comment: amended the post to make more sense - should have said 2.778 frames per image, not 2.778 seconds per image

Answer (score 3):

Another thing to try before shelling out for Twixtor is the default frame interpolation built-in to AE.

You'll see the frame-blending checkbox in the timeline window, click it once and you get the the frame mix mode, where one frame is dissolved into the next to create the interpolated frames. this is fast-n-easy, but it probably won't produce great results for you.

[image]

Click it twice to get the "pixel motion" mode which does some sort of motion analysis, and basically morphs one frame to the next. This can work really well, but it can sometimes also create weird artefacts, depending on your footage.

[image]

To see the frame blending in action in the comp window turn it on in the switch at the top of the timeline panel. You'll have to check that frame blending is on in your render settings too (in Best Quality it defaults to "On for checked layers" which is generally what you want).

[image]